# How to get the only output in c

Tags: c

I have written the following code for outputting a Fahrenheit temperature as Celsius:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    int fahr;
    int celsius;
    fahr=150;
    celsius=5*(fahr-32)/9;
    printf("fahr=150,celsius=%d",&celsius);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm new to C and I just can't understand what's wrong with it. It outputs a different value each time I run it.

Comment: [Turn on your compiler warnings.](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/814od7jah)

Comment: `printf("fahr=150,celsius=%d",&celsius);` => `printf("fahr=150,celsius=%d",celsius);`

Comment: also, you are missing \n at the end of your format string.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the line:

```c
printf("fahr=150,celsius=%d",&celsius);
```

What's wrong is that you're passing the ***address*** of the `celsius` variable rather than the *value* of the variable. The latter would just be `celsius` rather than `&celsius`.

> As an aside, the reason this address *changes* each time is probably to do with [ASLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) (address space layout randomisation), a feature that causes things to be loaded at different memory locations each time you run them. This makes it harder for hackers to create successful attack vectors against your code.

If you *remove* the `&` character, you'll no doubt see better results. You can *also* get rid of the `math.h` include as well, there's nothing in your code that uses it currently. C is able to do basic math (like addition and multiplication) without that header. You only need it if you want to do things like trigonometry or logarithms that are more complex. But, interestingly, not for complex numbers, which require `complex.h` :-)

I'm actually surprised you didn't see warnings with that code, most modern compilers will detect a mismatch between the format string and the arguments passed, such as:

```c
prog.c: In function ‘main’:
prog.c:9:27: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’,
   but argument 2 has type ‘int *’ [-Wformat=]
    9 | printf("fahr=150,celsius=%d",&celsius);
      |                          ~^  ~~~~~~~~
      |                           |  |
      |                           |  int *
      |                           int
```

If your compiler does *not* do this, I'd suggest figuring out how to get it to do so (if possible). For beginners, I'd also suggest telling it to treat all warnings as errors (such as with `gcc -Werror`).

That will force you to deal with warnings at compilation time rather than trying to figure out why your program is misbehaving *after* compilation.

---

Taking all my suggestions into account would make your code look like this (and including a bit of formatting/renaming/capitalising<sup>(a)</sup> to make it easier to read, though that's just my opinion):

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int fahrenheit, celsius;

    fahrenheit = 150;
    celsius = 5 * (fahrenheit - 32) / 9;
    printf("Fahrenheit = %d, Celsius = %d.\n", fahrenheit, celsius);

    return 0;
}
```

The output of that is:

```
Fahrenheit = 150, Celsius = 65.
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> I *believe* that "Fahrenheit" and "Celsius" should always be capitalised because they are always written as (for example) "degrees Celsius" (the unit "degrees" is not capitalised, just the qualifier indicating what *type* of degree it is).

Similarly, the term for the absolute scale should be capitalised only when referring to the Kelvin scale itself. When referring to the units, it's just "kelvins" rather than "degrees Kelvin". Though the abbreviation is still capitalised, such as "273.15 kelvins" being "273.15K".

Perhaps we should just start referring to the various temperatures as kelvins, fahrenheits, and celsii for consistency :-)